# URI with # char doesn't work on WCF RESTful service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C# and .NET framework 4.0

I have this URI:

```
http://localhost:7342/AdnLineService.svc/searchUsersByString?query=5%206%20#tags5&lookedAtBy=20
```

But, on WCF code, I don't get anything after the `#`.

**Do you know why?** It seems that I can't use a `#` char on an URI.
**Can I use `#` on an URI?**

Comment: Fragments identifiers (the part after the # in a URI) are a client-side feature. The client retrieves the resource without transmitting the fragment identifier to the server, and then locates the fragment with the specified fragment identifier in the resource.

Comment: To clarify @dtb comment - [fragments](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) are not strictly client-side feature, but indeed mostly ignored by servers and not transmitted by browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%23 is the same as #.See this [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06d055ee-a491-4a67-a5cb-1f4f37aa7db7/problem-while-passing-special-characters-in-uri-to-wcf-restful-service)

```
   public class Service
        {
            [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "Graphs/{library}/{subjectLocalPart}/{predicateLocalPart}/{objectPart}/{languageCode}")]
            public string CreateTriple(string library, string subjectLocalPart, string predicateLocalPart, string objectPart, string languageCode)
            {
                return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}", library, subjectLocalPart, predicateLocalPart, objectPart, languageCode);
            }
        }
        public static void Test()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

            Console.WriteLine("No '#'");
            Util.SendRequest(baseAddress + "/Graphs/myLib/123abc/content-HasA/456def-ghik/en-us", "PUT", "application/json", "0");

            Console.WriteLine("Simple '#' (encoded)");
            Util.SendRequest(baseAddress + "/Graphs/myLib/123abc/content%23HasA/456def%23ghik/en-us", "PUT", "application/json", "0");

            Console.WriteLine("Escaped '#'");
            Util.SendRequest(baseAddress + "/Graphs/myLib/123abc/content%2523HasA/456def%2523ghik/en-us", "PUT", "application/json", "0");

            Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
    public static class Util
    {
        public static string SendRequest(string uri, string method, string contentType, string body)
        {
            string responseBody = null;

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = method;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
            {
                req.ContentType = contentType;
            }

            if (body != null)
            {
                byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
                req.GetRequestStream().Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse resp;
            try
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            }

            if (resp == null)
            {
                responseBody = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Response is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
                foreach (string headerName in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", headerName, resp.Headers[headerName]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                if (respStream != null)
                {
                    responseBody = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream returned null");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*  ");
            Console.WriteLine();

            return responseBody;
        }
```